# Android Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android

When the user click on Camera, it open next screen after few seconds it throws `Fail to connect to camera service`

and it say  `cannot connect to camera`

This is my code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View viewLoad = LayoutInflater.from(CameraActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.camera, null);
    setContentView(viewLoad);

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    seletctedRetailer = bundle.getString("RetailerName");
    retailerCode = bundle.getString("RetailerCode");

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("Activity", "RetailerOrderSActivity");
    b.putString("RetailerName", seletctedRetailer);
    b.putString("RetailerCode", retailerCode);

    cameraIntent.putExtras(b);
    getParent().getParent().setTitle("Image Capture");
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);  

    vale +=1;

    Button imgMCancel =(Button)findViewById(R.id.imgMCancel);
    imgMCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CameraMainActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
            bundle.putString("Activity", "CameraMainActivity");
            bundle.putString("RetailerName", seletctedRetailer);
            bundle.putString("RetailerCode", retailerCode);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            View vi = SalesActivityGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CameraMainActivity", i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
            SalesActivityGroup.group.replaceView(vi);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            System.out.println("====YES======");
             Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
                image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  
        }
}
```

This is my layout :

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">


        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Cancel" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_red"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgMCancel" 
                >
       </Button>

       <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:text="Make Photo" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_red"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
        </Button>


    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
     <activity android:name=".sales.CameraActivity"              android:screenOrientation="landscape"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

I did this according to this link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/

Please help me what is an issue.My application contain Tab ActivityGroup.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I ended up just restarting the device and everything worked after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my application code -- hope it helps:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img_logo;
    public static Bitmap bitmap;
    public static  String selectedImagePath="";
    protected boolean _taken;   
    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";
    int count = 0;
    static String image1 = "";
    /*static String _path="";
    Bitmap bita;
    ParsingForCabDetails obj_ParsingForCabDetails;
    InputStream is;
    protected boolean _taken;   
    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";*/
    ProgressDialog pd;
    //ImageView iv;
    Button cancel,Ok;
    String alert="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        img_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_image);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_taken);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camerabtnupload);

        if(image1.length()<= 0)
        startCameraActivity();

        upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                if(image1.length() > 0){
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(SmallyTaxiTabbar.tabContext, "", "Loading....");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            LoardServer();
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                        }
                    }).start();

            }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Capture Image",2000).show();
            }


        });
        img_logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startCameraActivity();  
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                selectedImagePath= "";
                image1="";
                }
        });


    }


    public void LoardServer() {
    // this is use for upload image or save image   

    }


    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            pd.dismiss();
            finish();
            if(alert.length() >0 ){
                Log.d("hello","alert"+alert);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),alert, 2000).show();
            }
            else
                FindCabDetails.iv_camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            selectedImagePath= "";
            image1="";

        };
    };
    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        selectedImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/default"+count+".jpg";
        count++;
        File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case -1:
        onPhotoTaken();
        break;
        }
        }
        protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        bitmap = decodeFile();
        image1 = selectedImagePath;
        img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
        onPhotoTaken();
        }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
        }
        private Bitmap decodeFile() {
        try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream( selectedImagePath), null, o);
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
        break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale++;
        }
        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
        }
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                finish();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

}
```

**Use this camera.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bottoombg" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:textColor="#FBB917"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip" android:id="@+id/txtCabNametitle" android:text="Camera"></TextView>
            <Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/filter_btn1"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:text="Upload" android:layout_width="70dip" android:id="@+id/camerabtnupload"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:background="@drawable/btn_press_effect" android:layout_height="30dip" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:id="@+id/camera_taken" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_width="70dip"></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/camera_image" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="200dip" android:layout_width="200dip"></ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 21):

You forgot something in your manifest, look here [Camera Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

Add this to your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please add this information to your question! In your manifest the permission is missing!

Answer (score 6):

you have to unlock camera before getting preview display and lock camera properly before closing your app. If the camera is not locked properly, next time your app may throw exception. So that, you have to reboot your device...

Comment: I don't understand what's mean #locked properly# is

Comment: mCamera = Camera.open();
mCamera.unlock(); and at the end mCamera.lock();

Comment: Since API level 14, camera is automatically locked for applications in start().