# Android: Can I take a photo out of a web site and the automatically upload it?

Tags: android, camera, web

I am creating a `web application` (completely running on the server, no `Android App`) and I want to have the possibility to provide a button for taking a photo. After touching the button, the camera of this Android phone should get startet, let the user take a photo, and after that automatically upload the photo to my web app.

Is there a way to do this? If yes: How ?

Comment: i hope this link will help u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100351/android-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service/10100691#10100691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure web application without a client side component can not access the phone camera.

There is only a plan for introducing such a feature in future web browsers:

[HTML5 new features – accessing the native device camera](http://html5.sapnagroup.com/2011/07/html5-new-features-accessing-the-native-device-camera)

**Update (2012-04-25)**: I just read that the upcoming version 12 of Opera will include [camera support](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2012/04/17/camera-getusermedia-support).

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible in android. When you open your camera with intent it will return your result. In this result you will get URI of taken image and you can upload it on to your server.
Please visit this URL
[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

you will get some idea about how to accomplished your task.

Hope this will work for you.

thanks

Comment: tabb was asking if it is possible with a web-app - without an Android app.