# Failed to connect to camera service (RunTimeException) on open() when app has been running for a while

Tags: java, android, camera

This one's been making me lose my mind for the last few days.

The app I am working on is designed as a time clock of sorts to allow employees at my company to clock in and out. Accepts their ID number and snaps a picture for verification purposes if there was reason to suspect a "buddy punch." The tablets we are using are Samsung Galaxy Tab 3's with the 7 inch screen. The tablets are locked down and basically run the app all day with the screen on a 5 minute timeout.

The way I handle the camera is to open it when the app is active (screen is on and the activity is in the foreground), but not start the preview until someone starts typing in a number. This is all well and good. The problem is that sometimes for no reason that I've been able to discern, the app cannot connect to the camera service and gets a runtimeexception. Exiting and reloading the activity doesn't seem to fix it.

I release the camera when the activity loses focus (onPause) and open it back up in onResume. On my dev tablet, I can make the camera misbehave by rapidly starting and stopping the preview a bunch of times and just flailing on the tablet in general. The error thrown there gets handled by the error callback on the camera object and it's able to fix itself afterwards. Below is a stack trace.

Everything is declared properly in the manifest, and it works the majority of the time. It seems that the high use ones tend to get this thrown more often and the only fix I've found is restarting the device. I can post code snippets if need be.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? Could there be someplace I'm missing a camerae.release() call?

```
2014-01-06T18:43:58.645Z -- [myDebugTag] - getCamera: RunTimeException class java.lang.RuntimeException
2014-01-06T18:43:58.647Z -- [myDebugTag] - Fail to connect to camera service
2014-01-06T18:43:59.213Z -- [myDebugTag] - android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:348)
android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:307)
[mypackagename].fragments.CameraFrag.getCamera(CameraFrag.java:156)
[mypackagename].[myactivity].onResume([myactivity].java:1587)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5259)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2686)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my camera preview class. Perhaps not the prettiest. This class is inside a fragment. The activity tells the fragment when to stop the preview by doing camera.stopPreview and then hiding the view temporarily. It restarts it by calling startPreview and displaying the view again.

The activity also decides when to release the camera. It tells the fragment to release it and dispose of the objects in onPause and then restarts the camera preview and view in onResume.

```
/**
 * Used to display the camera preview to the screen. Handles taking a picture and saving it
 * 
 * @author [bagellord]
 */
private class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, ErrorCallback {
    /**
     * Reference to the camera (front facing)
     */
    private Camera          camera;
    /**
     * Used for displaying the preview
     */
    private SurfaceHolder   mHolder;
    /**
     * Camera id of the camera in use
     */
    private int             cameraId;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param con
     *            Context
     * @param cam
     *            The camera to use
     */
    public CameraPreview(Context con, Camera cam, int camId) {
        super(con);

        // Reference to the camera
        camera = cam;
        // Store the camera id
        cameraId = camId;
        // Get the holder for the surface view
        mHolder = getHolder();
        // Tell it to use this class as the call back
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // Add the error callback for the camera
        camera.setErrorCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Check to see if the surface exists
        if(mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // Stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // Holds the camera info
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        // Get the camera info
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

        // Orientation of the device
        int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        // Degrees
        int degrees = 0;

        // Check to see which way the device is oriented
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        // Used for setting the camera orientation
        int result;

        // Check to see if it is front or rear facing
        if(info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        // Set the orientation
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if(cameraEnabled) {
            // Set the callback to null
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            // Surface is gone, stop the preview
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Start the preview back up with the holder
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
        // Release the camera
        releaseCamera();
        // Log what happened
        TimeClockApp.logToFile(DEBUG_TAG, "CameraFrag.CameraPreview.onError error: " + error + " server died? "
                + (error == Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED));
        // Tell the parent that the camera failed and it will recreate it
        parent.camFailed();
    }

    /**
     * Start the preview
     */
    public void startPreview() {
        try {
            if(camera != null && mHolder != null) {
                // Tell the camera where to output the preview
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                // Start the preview
                camera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            TimeClockApp.logToFile(DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop the preview
     */
    public void stopPreview() {
        camera.stopPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Tell the camera to take a picture
     * 
     * @param timeStamp
     *            The timestamp for when it is being taken
     */
    public void takePicture() {
        // Tell the camera to take a picture.
        // The null parameters are for the shutter and the fallback for RAW format.
        // Third parameter is the code to run after it takes the photo
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                // Stores the picture
                File pictureFile = new File(
                        TimeClockApp.STORAGE_TEMP_IMG);
                // Make the parent directories
                pictureFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                // Delete the picture if it exists already for some reason
                pictureFile.delete();

                try {
                    // Output stream to write the file with
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                            pictureFile);
                    // Write the picture to the sd card
                    fos.write(data);
                    // Close the stream
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Error
                    TimeClockApp.logStackTrace("CameraFrag.CameraPreview.takePicture exception", e);
                }

                // Log that the picture was taken
                TimeClockApp.logToFile(DEBUG_TAG, "Temp picture taken");

                // Have to start previewing in the callback
                camera.startPreview();

                // Notify the parent activity that the picture has been taken
                parent.pictureTaken();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Release the camera so its resource is not locked up
     */
    private void releaseCamera() {
        // Make sure the camera object is not null
        if(camera != null) {
            // Workaround for a glitch
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            // Release the camera
            camera.release();
            // Set the camera to null
            camera = null;
            cameraEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/10100698/3036488

Comment: Hmm. They are running Android 4.2, so it's supposed to do lock and unlock automatically. Should I try it anyway?

Comment: Looking at the javadoc, it says you most likely don't need it if you're not doing video. I don't think that this is going to help matters as it has more to do with preview rather than actually getting the camera.

Comment: Can you post some code so I can test here?

Comment: I added the camera preview class above. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Any luck with it? I've been checking for memory leaks and crashes or bugs that could cause it to not release the camera but no dice.

Comment: I will try it tonight, when I got home... Will update here after that :)