# Android Error : Can't Connect to the Camara

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to open the default mobile camera on a button click. I have tried the following code:

```
  Camera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.CameraID);
  Camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent Intent3=new   Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
        startActivity(Intent3); 
    }
});
```

I also added the following permission in the Android Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I still see an error when I click on the camera button. The camera is loading but immediately after that I get a message **Can't connect to the camara** on screen.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the camera is being used by something else or if your policy manager has some setting where the camera is turned off?

Comment: i checked that my camara is on, there are another setting for that ???

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100351/android-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service

Comment: in which device you are testing your app??

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` instead of `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` Like this

```
Intent Intent3 = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Hmm, strange. try cleaning the project. Are you using the emulator or a real mobile device?

Comment: i used real device,micromax canvas

Comment: Check these out, I hope it works!

http://www.addictivetips.com/android/cant-connect-to-camera-error-on-android/

http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-nexus/144618-cant-connect-camera-2.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the android [camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29), a runtime exception is thrown:

```
if connection to the camera service fails (for example, 
if the camera is in use by another process or device policy manager has disabled the camera)
```

Have you tried checking if the camera is being used by something else or if your policy manager has some setting where the camera is turned off?

Make sure to call the release() method to release the camera when it is no longer needed, or you will not be able to use the camera. Perhaps as a sanity check, see if your regular camera works. If it says it fails, then your previous attempts at runni

Comment: how to check camara is open another else and how to off ??, my camara is working fine,but problem with only in it

Comment: Exit all apps that might be using the camera. Go to Settings>Battery and check if mm-qcamera-daemon  is running. Exit it and launch the app again to see if the camera connects.
Exit the app and relaunch it. This works most times. If it doesn’t try to force stop the app and clear the cache. The measures sound drastic but it has a high success rate.
If all else fails, restart your phone. Exit every app that’s running before restart it.

Comment: i try above all but i can't find solutions

Comment: @NiravMehta: Try Force stop all the apps that requires camera.. I am not sure It will work but atleast give a try..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you actually would have to launch your intent with the [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) action (instead of [INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA)). Then, in `onActivityResult` you have to get the data from the Intent: there you will find the reference to the image.
For more info see at [Receiving camera intent result](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive)

So use

```
MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

Instead of

```
MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA
```

**Edit**

You can use this method to check if camera is open by another app or not but keep this thing in mind that this method first acquire the camera

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (camera != null) camera.release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

If its acquire successfully then its mean that no other application is using this camera and don't forgot to release it again otherwise you will not able to acquire it again.

Its throws `RuntimeException` it means that camera is in use by another process or device policy manager has disabled the camera.

Comment: Are you testing this on emulator? Test it on another device.

Comment: @NiravMehta you can check if camera is open by another app,See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open default camera then use

```
 android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

instead of

```
 MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA
```

Comment: how to check camara is open another else and how to off ??, my camara is working fine,but problem with only in it